# Functional programming: Curry & Fold - what are the etymologies?

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming, history

1. [Curry](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/curry) & [Fold](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fold) - what are the etymologies in the programmatic sense?
   I do not see how any of the English meanings of these [homonyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym) is related to the functionality of these terms.
2. If you had to rename them to something more obvious - how would you do it?

Comment: Curry was the last name of the logician Haskell Curry.

Comment: Folding is sometimes called reducing. Functions that fold are sometimes called catamorphisms. I don't know that these are any better.

Comment: You can find references to the history of the *idea* of folding in Graham Hutton's classic [A tutorial on the universality and expressiveness of fold](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/fold.pdf), which traces it back to Kleene's recursion theory, APL's reduction operator, and FP's insertion operator, but those don't seem likely to get into the etymology.

Comment: Obviously if you wanted to rename currying to something more obvious, you would choose [schoenfinkelization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_Sch%C3%B6nfinkel).

Comment: One big problem with the term "fold" is that it is ambiguous in a way that the paradigmatic example of lists does not effectively expose. It means both "structure-preserving recursion" (a.k.a. "catamorphism", "iteration") and "structure-destroying accumulation" (a.k.a. "reduce", "crush"). The latter preserves only the structure of a monoid, so it's hilariously misleading to use free monoids (which have only monoid structure anyway) as the typical source type in an example. The term "fold" has thus become a source of misunderstanding (as has the acronym "ADT") and must thus be abandoned.

Comment: Excellent question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that the "fold" term comes mainly from the use of the word "fold" in phrases like ["to fold into..."](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fold-sth-in-fold-sth-into-something) which is a term most commonly used by chefs, I believe (I watch a lot of cooking shows...). We use it in the context of functional programming because we say that, for example, for lists, the head of the list is "folded into" the resulting of folding the tail. For example, the function `foldr` is a "recipe" for how to "cook" a list, and part of that recipe is "fold this into that", if you like.

The oldest reference to "folding" that I could find on the internet in the context of functional programming in [this](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/techreports/UCAM-CL-TR-75.pdf) report, published in 1985 by the University of Cambridge, which has this to say:

> The function *gather* applies a function of two arguments “between” each element of a list and a terminal value. [...] This function is also known as *reduce* or *fold* in other languages.

So clearly the term "fold" was at least somewhat common even 30 years ago!

Comment: Math is hard.. sorry.

Comment: That's great, I also thought of the cooking term when I first encountered the operator. In cooking, you're trying not to deflate the matrix batter; I think there must be a useful analogy in the computation, which also preserves or expresses a structure.

Comment: '...the head of the list is "folded into" the resulting of folding the tail.'  That's rather circular. Why not just call it Ouroborosization?  I understand that it can be hard to name new concepts immediately upon discovery for the purpose of publication, but 20, 30, 40 years on surely the CompSci profession can make the terminology less 'artistic'?

Answer (score 9):

Curry is the last name of Haskell Curry, a prominent 20th century logician [after whom Haskell got its name](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_(programming_language)).

And "folding" simply because the fold operator figuratively represents folding, like a hand of cards can be folded to look like a single card. Think of `foldr (+) 0 [1,2,3] == 6` as a hand of cards 1, 2 and 3 folded into a single card 6.

The word "reducing", which also means folding, can be illustrated using a similar analogy.

Of course, Haskell is more magic than even the bluffiest and luckiest game of poker, so folds in functional programming can actually produce a deck of cards that holds more cards than the hand it was folded from, or cards can be folded into cats, etc: `foldr (\i, acc -> [show i,show i,show i] ++ acc) [] [1,2,3] == ["1","1","1","2","2","2","3","3","3"]`. Therefore what started out as folding eventually evolved into an extremely universal operator that can produce `map` as well as `filter` etc, so don't get too carried away with the poker comparison and etymology.

---

As to what to name them to: renaming a dead person might not be the most ethical thing to do. The poor guy is so successful BOTH of his names are used for big things, and then you want to deprive him posthumously of his joy and rename him to something else? Unless perhaps that something else is Newton Watt Scoville or Kelvin Celsius Ângström, I'd seriously not attempt a rename.

However if you meant renaming the programming concept: it could instead be referred to by the name "ricing" in my hungry opinion. But Mr. Curry might still feel intimidated.

Folding could actually be renamed to bluffing, if you're not fulfilled by [the multitude of presently available names for it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)) — thanks to som-snytt for the constructive idea.

Comment: You fold in poker when you have a weak hand and bluffing is not an option. You use fold when you don't have a more powerful operator, and you're betting that no one will call your bluff and ask how your computation produces the result it does.

Comment: Is that a foundation for a future programming language in the paradigm of probabilistic and psychological programming, @som-snytt

Comment: @Erik Allik fold, a weaker version of recursion?

Comment: @rapt Think of it like a `for` loop in an imperative language.

Comment: @rapt it puts the "curse" back in "recurse." That's a good wikipedia link, thx. I have to read more wikipedia.